# Neo4j PARALLEL runtime query returns different result

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-parallel-runtime

I'm testing the new Neo4j PARALLEL runtime and am unable to pass my tests because my queries return different results (different elements order) compared to SLOTTED or PIPELINED. Do I need to somehow refine these queries so that they work properly on PARALLEL runtime? Do you have any docs on this? Or, are these refinements unnecessary, and the queries should return exactly the same result as on SLOTTED or PIPELINED?

Also, there is a limitation `It is not possible to use the parallel runtime if a change has been made to the state of a transaction.` https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/planning-and-tuning/runtimes/reference/

Unfortunately, I have many scenarios where I currently use `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2` to read data in the same transaction where I'm updating it. I would like to transition to the PARALLEL runtime, but I am unable to do so due to this limitation. Are you planning to overcome this limitation in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due the the Parallel nature of `Neo4j` these situations stem  as reasons for what you experienced.

- Results may not be deterministic, as different threads may finish at different times - use the `ORDER BY` clause
- `PARALLEL runtime` does not support updating queries, such as those using the `CREATE, MERGE, SET, DELETE, or REMOVE` - updating the graph in parallel may cause conflicts or inconsistencies to use  the same to  read  ,use `:begin` and `:commit` commands in `Cypher Shell` to control the transactions or another runtime, such as `SLOTTED or PIPELINED`, for the write queries.
- Also it does not support reading data that has been modified in the same transaction, as this may cause `concurrency` issues or `stale reads` aka you cannot use the `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2` procedure to read data that you have updated in the same transaction  - use another procedure, such as `apoc.cypher.doIt`, or split  transaction into two parts.

For situational restrictions  so mentioned , I doubt if they have plans to update.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I utilize the `ORDER BY` clause in my query. The key distinction is that `ORDER BY` comes after `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2` call, which is why it functions correctly. However, in the query without `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2` but with `PARALLEL runtime`, `ORDER BY` is integrated into the entire query. For some reason, this configuration results in an incorrectly ordered output.

Comment: [This page](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/planning-and-tuning/runtimes/reference/)   talks about differences and restrictions in Non Parallel Vs Parallel. There is no doc about order by clause but quite poss Parallel used different sort Algo compared to Non Parallel. All the other things I answered are confirmed